# Script issue creating mailbox in exchange management shell

Tags: shell, invoke-command, mailbox

I'm running a script in exchange management shell, using variables to output a command for creating user email accounts. Write-Host does a nice job showing the command string in the management shell, but of course does not execute it.   I've had success using Invoke-Expression followed by a variable representing a string using commandlets such as New-Addresslists and New-Accepteddomain, but when using Invoke-Expression with a variable containing the New-Mailbox commandlet, I get error messages.  How do I properly run a variable string from scripts specifically into the exchange management shell to create user email accounts?

Powershell / Exchange 2019

```
 $COMMAND = "New-Mailbox -Name $CustomerFirstName $CustomerLastName$ -UserPrincipalName $EmailPrefix@$CustomerDomainName -Password (ConvertTo-SecureString -String '$CustomerMailPassword' -AsPlainText -Force) -FirstName $CustomerFirstName -LastName $CustomerLastName"

  Invoke-Expression $COMMAND
```

Comment: Why not just `New-Mailbox -Name "$CustomerFirstName $CustomerLastName" -UserPrincipalName "$EmailPrefix@$CustomerDomainName" -Password (ConvertTo-SecureString -String '$CustomerMailPassword' -AsPlainText -Force) -FirstName $CustomerFirstName -LastName $CustomerLastName"`?

Comment: I forgot to mention the execution is running within an "IF" statement.  However, even when running on a separate line I get an error;   A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'smith''.
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [New-Mailbox], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,New-Mailbox
    + PSComputerName        : blabla

Comment: Yet, I can copy and past the result of the string variable and it executes perfectly.